# Create own JSON object from other JSON dict

Tags: python, json

I want to create my own JSON object because the original JSON data contains some unnecessary data that I don't need. Now I want to extract the whole `['values']` part and put that inside my own JSON object.

Original JSON that needs to get extracted:

```
{
  "headers": [
    "node",
    "subtask id",
    "status",
    "progress"
  ],
  "values": [
    [
      "testnet-gf-devel-0 git",
      "b4f34a0c-5446-11ea-8c29-1e0f691c9a55",
      "Finished",
      "100.0 %"
    ],
    [
      "Ruggu git",
      "b4f4cdde-5446-11ea-9018-1e0f691c9a55",
      "Finished",
      "100.0 %"
    ]
  ]
}
```

What I want my own JSON object to look like:

```
{
"values": [
        [
          "testnet-gf-devel-0 git",
          "b4f34a0c-5446-11ea-8c29-1e0f691c9a55",
          "Finished",
          "100.0 %"
        ],
        [
          "Ruggu git",
          "b4f4cdde-5446-11ea-9018-1e0f691c9a55",
          "Finished",
          "100.0 %"
        ]
      ]
}
```

Code:

```
async def parse_subtask_show(self, json_payload):
        json_object = json.loads(json_payload)

        data = {}
        for subtask in json_object['values']:
            data['subtasks'] = subtask[0]
            data['subtasks'] = subtask[1]
            data['subtasks'] = subtask[2]
            data['subtasks'] = subtask[3]
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        print(json_data)
```

But that just outputs `{"subtasks": "100.0 %"}` . I think I might be overriding some of the data? How would I go on about this?

Comment: At least when you're dealing with the `json` module, there really isn't such a thing as a "JSON object". The functions we use parse JSON from strings into Python dictionaries, and output dicts as strings which contain JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think I might be overriding some of the data?

That is precisely what you are doing, namely here:

```
    for subtask in json_object['values']:
        data['subtasks'] = subtask[0]
        data['subtasks'] = subtask[1]
        data['subtasks'] = subtask[2]
        data['subtasks'] = subtask[3]
```

You simply overwrite whatever is at the the key `'subtasks'`, so it will keep only the last one.

I think you just want:

```
data = {'values': json_object['values']}
```

Comment: That was really simple! I had an idea that it should be simple, but i'm not that experienced on the JSON field, YET. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're making this much harder than it needs to be. Just extract the object you want.

```
myobject = {"values": json_object["values"]}
json_data = json.dumps(myobject)
print(json_data)
```

I'm not sure what `data['subtasks']` has to do with this, you don't show that in the desired result.

Comment: Yeah I was also thinking I made it a lot harder than it should be. Your answer it correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can achieve what you want.

```
async def parse_subtask_show(self, json_payload):
        json_object = json.loads(json_payload)
        json_data = json.dumps(json_object['values'])
        print(json_data)
```